# PHP - how to set up URL after sending form?

Tags: php, forms, url, post, get

I have a website (`www.website.com`) and on the homepage is a form, where the user set up a city. After sending the form, I am trying to have the following URL address:

```
www.website.com/city-name
```

But I am lost a bit here, because I am not sure, how to set up the form (GET or POST is better for this need?), and `.htaccess`.

Could anyone help with this? Thank you

Comment: Do you need this URL to request this page direct over the URL?

Comment: Yes, I do. When someone set up `http://www.website.com/city-name`, I would like the accessible content there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the form is submitted you could redirect your users via PHP redirect, or am i missing something?

```
header('Location: http://www.website.com/city-name');
```

**But be careful, this can only be used before you send any output!**

PHP: [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: But for doing this, I need to also have set up the `.htaccess`, or not? Because without that, I would get just 404 error. But how to correctly set up `.htaccess` for this?

Comment: you dont have to set up .htaccess for this, unless you have any weird rewrites set in it. maybe you could add your .htaccess contents?

Answer (score 0):

You could let the submit button run a javascript function.
In that javascript function, use

`var cityName = document.getElementById("the textarea id").value`

to get the value the user typed for the city name.
Then redirect to the right page:

`window.location='http://www.website.com/' + cityName`